# Node.js: Saving survey form values to txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have what I think may be a simple question for many out there, but for me is giving me a headache. I created a simple survey in `HTML` using a basic `<form>` structure.

The survey is rendered using Node.js, but once the user has selected their inputs, I'd like to save the values into a `txt` file using Node.js and  fs.writefile or fs.appendfile.

So, this has not been working out well, despite me trying to look up various articles and videos and extract details that I thought would relate to my problem directly. I uploaded the code I have (HTML and JS for Node file). Each multiple choice value, which are all radio button inputs, has a value that if chosen, I want to write into the txt file.

So, any help on what I could do better would be great.

Also, I am new to Node.js so to some that may explain my JS Node code.

Thanks!

```
  Node.js code:

    var http = require('http');
    var fs  = require('fs');
    var formidable = require("formidable");
    var util = require('util');

    var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    fs.readFile('Form.html', function (err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Content-Length': data.length
    });
    res.write(data);
    //console.log(data);
    res.end();
    });

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log(err,fields, files);
    var data = JSON.stringify(files);
    //console.log(data);

    fs.appendFile('Phone.txt', data, function(err){
        if(err){throw err;}
    else{console.log('saved!');};}); });  }).listen(8080);
    console.log("server listening on 8080");
```

Comment: I would note that generally you should be saving this type of data to a proper database and not directly to a file.

Comment: You will need a request handler on your HTTP server that handles in the incoming form data and you will need to start your server properly and you will need a form in your web page that posts the data to the server.  The last part of your code looks jumpled as if it was not properly pasted into the questoin.

Comment: Actually that's all the code I had,  and this was an internet programming class assignment and the teacher wanted us to save it to a txt file.

Comment: I did not post the form into the page as it is quite lengthy but I believe the Form.html is referenced in the code since it displays in the browser when I go to open an internet browser

Comment: When I say page I meant this one, where I posted my question.  But if it helps to upload my HTML file I totally can?